# Change success message on applying coupon code

Tags: magento-2.1, coupon, messages, success-message

In Magento 2.x, By default, we can set coupon codes from **Marketing->Cart Price Rules**.

I've added a test code and it's working as expected. When I added the code in cart page (`mysite.com/checkout/cart`) ,

I see the success message as follows:-

***You used coupon code "TestCode1".***

How to change this message to include whatever text I need to put?

Comment: Simplest way first check inline edit option, then try to find the sentence in side the checkout js files,

Answer (score 2):

You can override File named `CouponPost.php`.

To achieve this you can create preference for this.

> Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\CouponPost" type="Vednor\Module\Controller\Rewrite\Cart\CouponPost" />
```

> Vendor/Module/Controller/Rewrite/Cart/CouponPost.php

```
namespace Vednor\Module\Controller\Rewrite\Cart;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class CouponPost extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    ......
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
) {
    parent::__construct($context);

    .......
}


public function execute()
{

    // Keep all code as it is, Just change message as per your need.

}
}
```

Hope it will help you. !!

Comment: You mean first I should copy all the content from **CouponPost.php** right? I think this can be a better answer if you can somewhat improve this to be a complete answer. start from beginning. Where is **CouponPost.php** file located, This is about creating a custom module. What files(except the default files) should be there etc..

Comment: Check here. https://github.com/TBSMage/StackExchange225264

Comment: Thanks..This will absolutely help more than just me

Comment: @Joey, If it resolve your problem, Give upvote and accept answer to help others.

Answer (score 2):

Just update text in your translation CSV file like below example

> "You used coupon code ""%1"".","Your custom text ""%1""."

Translation file something like below

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/ThemeName/i18n/en_US.csv

Comment: I tried this solution, but sometimes translation csv is not working properly in my theme. maybe a problem with my theme. I also tried inline translation, which worked for me in this instance. anyway thank you for helping out

Comment: Do you have multi language?

Comment: I have UK and US

Comment: Which command do you use for deployment?

Comment: en_US and en_GB

Comment: show your command for deploy static content.

Comment: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB and 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US

Comment: Run this command and check your CSV changes : php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB en_US

Comment: I did. I even tried reindexing and compiling. doesn't work. as I said before, could be something wrong with my theme :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77232/discussion-between-suresh-chikani-and-joey).

Comment: Create new CSV like :   app/design/frontend/Vendor/ThemeName/i18n/en_GB.csv

Answer (score 1):

You can change this message from `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/CouponPost.php` file.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class CouponPost extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart
{
    /**
     * Sales quote repository
     *
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * Coupon factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\CouponFactory
     */
    protected $couponFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
     * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\CouponFactory $couponFactory
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\CouponFactory $couponFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $scopeConfig,
            $checkoutSession,
            $storeManager,
            $formKeyValidator,
            $cart
        );
        $this->couponFactory = $couponFactory;
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Initialize coupon
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $couponCode = $this->getRequest()->getParam('remove') == 1
            ? ''
            : trim($this->getRequest()->getParam('coupon_code'));

        $cartQuote = $this->cart->getQuote();
        $oldCouponCode = $cartQuote->getCouponCode();

        $codeLength = strlen($couponCode);
        if (!$codeLength && !strlen($oldCouponCode)) {
            return $this->_goBack();
        }

        try {
            $isCodeLengthValid = $codeLength && $codeLength <= \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart::COUPON_CODE_MAX_LENGTH;

            $itemsCount = $cartQuote->getItemsCount();
            if ($itemsCount) {
                $cartQuote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
                $cartQuote->setCouponCode($isCodeLengthValid ? $couponCode : '')->collectTotals();
                $this->quoteRepository->save($cartQuote);
            }

            if ($codeLength) {
                $escaper = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Escaper::class);
                $coupon = $this->couponFactory->create();
                $coupon->load($couponCode, 'code');
                if (!$itemsCount) {
                    if ($isCodeLengthValid && $coupon->getId()) {
                        $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->setCouponCode($couponCode)->save();
                        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                            __(
                                'You used coupon code "%1".',
                                $escaper->escapeHtml($couponCode)
                            )
                        );
                    } else {
                        $this->messageManager->addError(
                            __(
                                'The coupon code "%1" is not valid.',
                                $escaper->escapeHtml($couponCode)
                            )
                        );
                    }
                } else {
                    if ($isCodeLengthValid && $coupon->getId() && $couponCode == $cartQuote->getCouponCode()) {
                        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                            __(
                                'You used coupon code "%1".',
                                $escaper->escapeHtml($couponCode)
                            )
                        );
                    } else {
                        $this->messageManager->addError(
                            __(
                                'The coupon code "%1" is not valid.',
                                $escaper->escapeHtml($couponCode)
                            )
                        );
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You canceled the coupon code.'));
            }
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('We cannot apply the coupon code.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
        }

        return $this->_goBack();
    }
}
```

You can override this controller file by custom module.

Follow this link: https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-controller-override-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. so far this is the most complete answer. if you can please improve this little more, so someone else can benefit from this

Comment: it is not recommended to edit core files.