# English to english translation problem magento2

Tags: magento2, localisation, magento2.3, translate, i18n

I am translating the text`("You canceled the coupon code.")` with `"Thank you for canceling the coupon code"` (This is just english to english translation) from `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\CouponPost` in my custom module. For this I have custom module and created `en_US.csv` file under `app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/i18n/en_US.csv`. My module is already enabled and I have so `observers`,`plugins` which are working fine.

But somehow this translation is not working on frontend side, anyone has similar problem? or am i missing something? or english to english translation is not possible?

I already tried `cache:clean` , `di:compile` :`static-content:deploy`.

I already checked [Change success message on applying coupon code](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225264/change-success-message-on-applying-coupon-code) question